# React DropDown Component on FabricJS Canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fabricjs

I am able to create a TextBox on FabricJS Canvas. But I am unable to create a Dropdown on FabricJS Canvas. There is an option to create a TextBox on FabricJS using **fabric.Textbox** but the same cannot be done for dropdown. Please see my codes below on how I create a Textbox on FabricJs and kindly advise on how I can do the same If I want to create a DropDown component on a FabricJS canvas.

If there any options other than using FabricJS that allows more flexibility and it is abetter option for creating complex components, kindly share a link or source to help me.

My Codes on how I create a Textbox on FabricJS canvas

```
export default function TextBox(props) {
useEffect(() => {
var text = new fabric.Textbox("Enter Text Here", {
  left: 10,
  top: 50,
  width: 294,
  height: 60,
  fontStyle: "normal",
  color: "#999999",
  fontWeight: 375,
  fontSize: 12,
  backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
  borderColor: "#ABB3BF",
  padding: 20,
  showTextBoxBorder: true,
  textboxBorderColor: "green",
  borderStyle: "solid",
});

props.canvas.add(text);
});

return null;
}
```

Comment: There is no built-in fabric.js object that would do anything like that (and I doubt any other canvas library would, really). Why do you want to draw the dropdown on canvas though? It's not that it's impossible, it's just so much easier to make components like dropdown in regular DOM.

Comment: @shkaper I need to create a playground where users can drag and drop components to create a form. This form can be shared via a link to accept user input and submitted back to the creators of the form, just like the way google forms work. Can you advise how I can achieve that using regular components?

Comment: Take a look at how [form.io](https://formio.github.io/formio.js/app/sandbox) does it. They have a WYSIWYG form builder and a JSON schema for it. I'm not endorsing it, this is just the first opensource project that turned up after a quick search.

Comment: @shkaper I did look at formio. But the editor and the sidebar for the WYSIWYG are bundled together. I need to be able to create my own sidebar components while leveraging on formio's editor workspace. this seems not to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do that by default in FabricJS. But you can add custom control on fabric objects, then add your submenu/dropdown component as a context menu. There are several context-menu libraries for ReactJS, like "React-Contextify".